# How can I use a variable string with getRangeList() to select noncontinguous rows in a Sheet?

Tags: string, variables, google-sheets, range

I need to be able to create variable strings that will be used by getRangeList() to select non-contiguous rows in a Google Sheet. The string will be different every time it's run. It might be gathering 20 rows one time and 4 the next (always in 2-row sets, incidentally). When I record a macro to select sample rows 8 and 9 and then 14 and 15, it gives me this:

```
function testMe() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRangeList(['8:9', '14:15']).activate();
};
```

Running this does fine--selecting the four rows. I hoped that this meant I could simply use script to create a string like "'8:9', '14:15'" as a variable and embed it in the code, as in:

```
function testMe() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var myRange = "'8:9', '14:15'";
  spreadsheet.getRangeList([myRange]).activate();
};
```

This gives me the error "Exception: Range not found."

I considered that the problem was in the special characters and tried this instead:

```
function testMe() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var myRange = "\'8:9\', \'14:15\'";
  spreadsheet.getRangeList([myRange]).activate();
};
```

This gives me the same error: "Exception: Range not found."

I wondered if the problem was with the brackets inside the parentheses and tried this:

```
function testMe() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var myRange = "[\'8:9\', \'14:15\']";
  spreadsheet.getRangeList(myRange).activate();
};
```

I got this error: "Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRangeList."

I got the same error when I tried it with the brackets embedded in the string with the first example--the one without the slashes for the special characters, so:

```
function testMe() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var myRange = "['8:9', '14:15']";
  spreadsheet.getRangeList(myRange).activate();
};

How can I create variable strings that will work with getRangeList() to select non-contiguous pairs of rows?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function testMe() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var myRange = []
  myRange.push("8:9")
  myRange.push("14:15")
  spreadsheet.getRangeList(myRange).activate();
};
```

myRange is an array

Comment: Just to add some explanation: rangeList needs to be ana array. This means that instead of `var myRange = "\'8:9\', \'14:15\'";` it needs to be `var myRange = ['8:9', '14:15'];`. See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getrangelista1notations).

Comment: Brilliant, @ziganotschka! It worked. I also made sure that creating the array elements as text strings in a variable would work as you described, and it did. Thank you so much!